# How to cast unsigned integer to enum using CMSIS API

Tags: c, misra, cmsis

I am using [CMSIS API](https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/General/html/index.html) in my C program for ARM Cortex-M CPU.
CMSIS defines `NVIC_DisableIRQ` function as

```
__STATIC_INLINE void __NVIC_DisableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn);
```

IRQn_Type is a `typedef enum`, like

```
typedef enum IRQn
{

  NonMaskableInt_IRQn           = -14,     /*  2 Non Maskable Interrupt */
  HardFault_IRQn                = -13,     /*  3 HardFault Interrupt */
  .....
  Interrupt0_IRQn               =   0,
  Interrupt1_IRQn               =   1,
  Interrupt2_IRQn               =   2,
} IRQn_Type;
```

So, given that I would like to call `NVIC_DisableIRQ`, as

```
NVIC_DisableIRQ( (IRQn_Type )(SCB->ICSR -16);
```

and this fails MISRA check

> note 9034: cannot assign 'unsigned32' to different essential type
> 'enum (IRQn)' [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.3, required]

I understand  why MISRA complains, but that is a practical solution for this?
That I found is to create huge switch/case , are any other solutions/hacks available ?

Comment: What's `SCB->ICSR`, a `volatile uint32_t`?

Comment: Your  `enum IRQn` has to be signed for the negative values, but an `uint32_t` or equivalent can not store negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `SCB->ICSR -16` results in a `uint32_t` result, then you can't assign that to an `enum` variable (10.3) nor are you allowed to cast it to an `enum` (10.5). This is because enums have implementation-defined size and signedness.

I suppose there might be various dirty tricks to dodge MISRA, but that defeats the rather sound rationale of these rules, which boil down to: don't use signed operands all over your code to make it go haywire in various subtle and severe ways. Such as changing the default compiler enum type causing all interrupts to change behavior - that is *not good* - dangerous as can be.

The root of the problem is the `enum` type and CMSIS function `__NVIC_DisableIRQ` that requires an `enum`. If that one had been written differently, we could have used unsigned types. Pretty strange that sloppy non-MISRA compliant libraries are still getting rolled out in the year 2020.

I would suggest that you drop that function and write a custom one. Most of these functions are just wrappers around simple single-line assembler instructions or register writes anyway, so if you have access to the function implementation, it might not be much of an effort.

Note that MISRA-C (10.5) allows casts from enum to unsigned, so if you make an API based on `uint32_t` you may still be able to pass on the enum values by casting them.